# Do I keep anything when I start a new game?

Tags: mystic-messenger

If I finish the game and start a new one, do I keep anything like my hourglasses or hearts? Or do I have to start from nothing? I bought some hourglasses with real money, so I'd like to know if they're going to disappear!

Answer (score 1):

yes you keep everything! you even keep the photos and guest descriptions